# Reusability of reducers at different levels of app state structure

Tags: redux

For example we have reducer `photos`, which handles array of photos via actions `ADD_PHOTO` and `REMOVE_PHOTO`. And if we have arrays `users` and `posts`, they both have field for array of photos.

So, in order to avoid code duplicates I'm going to do the following:

1. Create reducer `user = combineReducers(..., photos, ...)`
2. Create actionCreator `updateUser`

```
    const updateUser = (id, subAction) => ({
        type: UPDATE_USER,
        payload: {
            id,
            subAction
        }
    })
```

3. Create reducer `users` (Here I'm using Immutable.js)

```
    function users(state = List(), action) {
        switch (action.type) {

            //...

            case UPDATE_USER:
                const { id, subAction } = action.payload
                const index = state.findIndex(user => user.id == id)

                return state.updateIn(
                [index, 'photos'],
                state => photos(state, subAction)
                )
                break

            //...

            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

4. And then I'm going to use all of it like this:

   `dispatch(updateUser(id, addPhoto(url)))`

---

Is this a correct solution of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply dispatch both in the place where this is initiated by the user?

```
dispatch(updateUser(id));
dispatch(addPhoto(url));
```

I haven't come across this pattern you're applying before. It seems a bit unusual that one reducer is responsible for reducing state of another. Creates a dependency between them that doesn't feel very pure. I'm not even sure one reducer should be able to/can see the state of another.

So no idea about "correct", but I'd say it's not ideal to do it your way. I'd try dispatching both sequentially or maybe in a sort of meta-action that takes care of nested updates and dispatches actions to multiple reducers.